Please help me identify an old movie about parallel worlds adventure
When I was little, I saw an old movie that's still obsessing me now. The language is not English, so it's difficult for me to identify the movie.
It is about a married man. His current life is neither successful nor happy. Then somehow he discovers a corridor that leads him to an other world, where all people he knows, including himself are the same. The only thing different is that all of his mistakes, failures no longer exist in this world. The copy of him is living a very happy life.
Then he tries to kill his copy to steal his life and never come back to his actual miserable world. The drama come along when he figures out that people in that parallel world also came from the actual world, and they already killed their copies.
That's all I can remember. And i'm really want to watch it again to recall how it ends. Please help me with this!

Can you narrow the countries a bit? Did the actors look Asian or European?

I think you might be searching for the 2009 German movie The Door (orig.: Die Tür), starring Mads Mikkelsen and based on a novel by Akif Pirinçci. It is not very old, though (but you didn't really specify a time frame), but it does fit your plot description pretty well, even if it isn't an alternative world but merely the past.
The story is about a father who causes the death of his daughter by carelessness. After years later and becoming a bitter wreck he suddenly discovers a secret door that leads to the past, where his daughter is still alive. There he ends up (accidentally?) killing his past self and trying to live the happy life he once lost and make things better. But things soon get out of hand when he realizes that it is not too easy to uphold his past happiness and that he isn't actually the only one who discovered that door and its possibilities for reliving a past life.

That's the one. Many thanks Napoleon Wilson
